# Phpmyadmin doesn't show the login page

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, appserver

Phpmyadmin doesn't show the login page to access into MySQL Database. I try accessing http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/ but it shows the blank page. What should I do ? T^T

Answer (score 0):

try installing an older version of phpMyAdmin or try the sqlbuddy !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you :) finally i can do it. i found that apache2.2 is not start and it show 
"Windows could not start the Apache2 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Micorsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1." I try to change port in Apache2\conf\httpd.conf to port8000 and now i can access to http://localhost:8000/phpMyAdmin/ :D